# Accessing remote MQ server from MQ.NET

Tags: c#, websphere, ibm-mq, mq

How do i access the remote server of queue manager from my MQ.NET?

i.e. If the queue manager is IBM MQ 7x, i would like to enable auto reconnect, if not no auto reconnect. Like, is there any attribute to find the version # of MQ installed in the remote server?

if remote queue manager of remote server is  7x

```
var mqQMgr = new MQQueueManager("My queue Manager", MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR, "my channel name", "my connection name");
```

else

```
var mqQMgr = new MQQueueManager("My queue Manager", "my channel name", "my connection name");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is possible to determine the version of the queue manager until after you've made the connection. A couple of options would be:

1. Have a parameter that the user sets to specify the version of MQ and if the version is greater than or equal to 7 include the `MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR` option.
2. Connect to the queue manager as though it were running an earlier version of MQ, determine the version of the queue manager using `mqQMgr.getCommandLevel()` and then if it is greater or equal to 700 disconnect and reconnect to the queue manager with the `MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR` option.

Comment: Paul H-This one helps - mqQMgr.CommandLevel(), but before i connect, can't i check the version # without asking the user to configure a property?

Comment: @Sharpeye500 When you say configure a property are you talking about the queue manager name, channel name and hostname/port? If so, you'll need the user to specify these parameters in order to connect to the queue manager and find out what version its running.

Comment: Paul H -Something like the dspmqver from command prompt will yield the version info of the MQ client. Similarly any other command to get the version info of the MQ server.